# Minimize Those Ones

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

Your task is to build a natural number using the fewest number of ones and only the operators `+` or `-`. For example, the number seven can be written `1+1+1+1+1+1+1=7`, but it can also be written as `11-1-1-1-1=7`. The first one uses `7` ones, while the latter only uses `6`. Your task is to return the minimum number of ones that can be used given the input of some natural number, `n`.

This is code golf, so the shortest valid code in bytes wins.

#### Test cases

Input => Output

```
0 => 2 (since 1-1=0)
7 => 6
121 => 6
72 => 15
1000 => 7
2016 => 21
```

Comment: Nice first challenge. I'd suggest including more test cases. Is "VALID OUTPUTS" a mistake, given that there's a single output? Also, is 0 a valid input, and if so, what should be output?

Comment: This is an interesting challenge. You may want to add an explanation for the outputs, change `VALID OUTPUTS`. It's your choice, but generally people like **bold** or *italics* instead of CAPITAL LETTERS (they make it look like shouting instead of emphasis). Bold is `**bold text**`, and italics is `*italics text*`. You could also use `### Text` for bold-er text. Anyway, welcome to PPCG!

Comment: You should make a computer-readable table or list of test cases that people can run their code on. See [this tip](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8101/20260).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because this question is of a duplicate of the current (active!!) golfing challenge over at https://codefights.com/challenges. Even if the OP is also the author of the original challenge on codefights (which I doubt), the question should be closed until the challenge on codefights isn't active any more.

Comment: @Jakube the [direct link](https://codefights.com/challenge/3hvztAQWAnRFEpvvd) could've been helpful, but I agree. I will vote to close.

Comment: Is it gone yet?

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>127</s> <s>126</s> 87 bytes

```js
f=(n,z=2,m=n*9+'',r=m.replace(/./g,1))=>n?m.length+(m<'55'?f(n- --r/10,0)-1:f(r-n,0)):z
```

```html
Input: <input type="number" oninput="result.textContent=f(this.value)"> Result: <span id="result"></span>
```

Should work to about 10<sup><s>14</s>15</sup> at which point you start running into JavaScript's integer limits. Explanation:

```
f=(                             Recursive function
 n,                             Parameter
 z=2,                           Zero workaround
 m=n*9+'',                      Magic
 r=m.replace(/./g,1)            Find repunit not less than than n
)=>n?                           Nothing to do if n is zero
 m.length+                      Assume subtracting from repunit
 (m<'55'?                       Should we subtract from repunit?
  f(n- --r/10,0)                No, so subtract previous repuint
   -1:                          Which is one 1 shorter
  f(r-n,0)):                    Subtract from repunit
 z                              Return special case if n is zero
```

This uses the `n*9` magic twice; firstly, it gives me the length of the next repunit, secondly, if the first two digits of `n*9` are `55` or higher, then we need to subtract `n` from that next repunit, otherwise we need to subtract the previous repunit (which is calculated by subtracting 1 and dividing by 10). This should work up to 10<sup>15</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```
ffqQvs+R1Y^c3"+-
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ffqQvs%2BR1Y%5Ec3%22%2B-&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A7%0A121%0A1000&debug=0)

Brute force algorithm. The necessary strings are generated by taking all lists whose elements are `['+', '-', '']` of length equal to the number of 1s being tested, appending a 1 to each, and concatenating to a single string. These strings are then evaluated and compared with the input. This is repeated until a successful string is found.

Some strings with a leading `+` or `-` are tested, but this isn't a problem. It would be if the input was negative though.

It can run up to length 9 before it becomes too slow.

**Explanation:**

```
ffqQvs+R1Y^c3"+-
ffqQvs+R1Y^c3"+-"T    Implicit variable introduction
                      Q = eval(input())
f                     Starting with T = 1 and counting upwards, repeat until true.
                      The value of T where the result is first true is output.
           c3"+-"     Chop "+-" into thirds, giving ['+', '-', '']
          ^      T    Form every list with those elements of length T.
 f                    Filter over those lists, lambda var Y.
      +R1Y            Append a 1 to each element of the list.
     s                Concatenate.
    v                 Eval.
  qQ                  Compare for equality with the input.
                      The inner filter will let through the successful cases.
                      The outer filter will stop when there is a successful case.
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

```js
f=(n,i=3)=>eval([...s=i.toString(3)].map(d=>"-+"[d]||"").join`1`+".0")-n?f(n,i+1):s.length-1
```

```html
n = <input type="number" oninput="R.textContent=f(this.value)" /><pre id="R"></pre>
```

### Explanation

Recursive function. This generates all possible permutations of `1`s separated by either `+`, `-` or nothing. It does this by incrementing a base-3 number, turning it into an array of digits, converting each digit `0` to `-`, `1` to `+` and `2` to an empty string, then joining them together with `1`s. The resulting string is `eval`d as a JavaScript statement which returns the result of the equation.

Because the operators are joined with `1`s in between (like `+1+1+1+`), there are `length - 1` `1`s. The first operator is ignored (because `+1` = `1`, `<nothing>1` = `1` and it's a number so there will never be a leading `0` for `-`) and the final operator is also ignored (by appending `.0` to the equation).

#### Higher Output Version, 96 bytes

The other version can't return outputs higher than ~10 because of the recursion call stack limit. This version uses a for loop instead of recursion, so it can return outputs up to ~33. The amount of time required increases exponentially though so I don't recommend testing it.

```js
n=>eval('for(a=3;eval([...s=a.toString(3)].map(d=>"-+"[d]||"").join`1`+".0")-n;)a++;s.length-1')
```

Comment: This sounds overcomplicated, I like it.