# There can be only 1!

Tags: math, code-challenge, metagolf, test-battery

Your task is, given a positive integer `n`, to generate an expression that equals the number `n`.

The catch is: you're only allowed the number `1` in the output.

The operators at your disposal are:

- `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`

  - `/` is floating-point division (so `5/2 = 2.5`).
- `sqrt` (as `s`)
- `ceil` and `floor` (as `c` and `f` respectively)
- `!` (factorial)

  - The factorial, in this case, only works for positive integers.

You are also allowed to stack `1`'s together, so something like `11` is acceptable in the output. However, they count as the same number of `1`'s that's in the number (so `11` counts as 2 `1`'s).

You must also include brackets in the output, so that the expression in the output, when executed through the order of operations, will result in the input.
They do not count as operations, though.

### Examples:

- Input = 24, one possible output = `(1+1+1+1)!`
- Input = 11, one possible output = `11`
- Input = 5, one possible output = `c(s((1+1+1+1)!))`

  - The ceiling of the square root of `24` is `5`.

### Rules:

- You are guaranteed that the input is a positive integer from `1` to `2^31-1`.
- Your program must work for any positive integer up to `2^31-1`, even if they are not tested.
- Your program must finish processing all outputs for all numbers in the set in 1 hour.
- The results for every run of the program must be exactly the same - also, no seeds.
- You are only allowed to hardcode the expressions for a maximum of 10 numerical values.
- You are not allowed to have imaginary numbers anywhere in the output (so no `s(some negative number)`).
- You are also not allowed to have numbers larger than `2^31-1` or smaller than `-2^31+1` anywhere in the output, even when they are `sqrt`ed or `/`ed (so no `(((1+1+1)!)!)!` or `((1+1+1+1)!)!`).

### Set of Numbers:

```
945536, 16878234, 32608778, 42017515, 48950830, 51483452, 52970263, 54278649, 63636656, 78817406, 89918907, 90757642, 95364861, 102706605, 113965374, 122448605, 126594161, 148064959, 150735075, 154382918, 172057472, 192280850, 194713795, 207721209, 220946392, 225230299, 227043979, 241011012, 248906099, 249796314, 250546528, 258452706, 276862988, 277140688, 280158490, 286074562, 308946627, 310972897, 322612091, 324445400, 336060042, 346729632, 349428326, 352769482, 363039453, 363851029, 392168304, 401975104, 407890409, 407971913, 425780757, 459441559, 465592122, 475898732, 482826596, 484263150, 506235403, 548951531, 554295842, 580536366, 587051904, 588265985, 588298051, 590968352, 601194306, 607771869, 618578932, 626776380, 667919873, 681786366, 689854904, 692055400, 697665495, 711608194, 734027104, 750869335, 757710567, 759967747, 777616154, 830071127, 833809927, 835873060, 836438554, 836945593, 863728236, 864158514, 871273503, 881615667, 891619600, 897181691, 918159061, 920521050, 924502226, 929983535, 943162304, 950210939, 950214176, 962610357, 974842859, 988572832
```

(These are 100 random numbers from 1 to 1 billion.)

### Scoring System:

Your score is determined like so:

- Your program will be tested against the random numbers in the set.

  - You must provide the output generated using the random numbers in the set (either inside your answer or as a pastebin link).
- Your then have two "scores": A primary score and a secondary score.

  - Your primary score is `(no. of 1's in output)*(no. of operators in output)`. If your primary score is the lowest, you win.
  - Your secondary score is the time of your upload, in GMT, and in 24-hour time. So, if you upload your program on September 12th, 00:00 GMT, then your score is `12/09/2016, 00:00` (use `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM` for your formatting).

Display your score like so:

```
(language name)
Primary Score = (primary score)
Secondary Score = (secondary score)
(no. of 1's) `1`'s, (no. of operators) operators
```

Replace all the things in the brackets with your language name, primary score and secondary score respectively.

### Current Winner:

#### The current winner is @ChrisJefferson, who has a primary score of `3,810,660`.

Comment: Advice not a rule, but [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8195/20283) is a pretty good argument for why golf as a tie breaker is problematic. Sorry I didn't spot this in the sandbox...

Comment: Related [math.SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/48633/24654).

Comment: I agree with trichoplax that the tiebreaker should be the answer to sooner reach its shortest score.

Comment: @ETHProductions How would that be enforced, though?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Parentheses are not operations, but are required.

Comment: You can look through the history of answers and see which one reached its final score first.

Comment: Is `/` integer division or floating point division ?

Comment: @TonHospel It is floating point division.

Comment: I assume there is also a limit on negative intermediate results, e.g. `t >= -2^31` ?

Comment: @TonHospel Yeah, that's right.

Comment: does the answer have to be in base 10? could I do it in binary?

Comment: While it's too late to change now, in future I'd consider a different optimisation condition. This one has the (for me) irritating feature that it is a "global" optimisation -- you can't improve your result for each number in isolation.

Of course, if you wanted it to have that property, that's fine, but it makes the problem much harder. Either adding 1s and ops, or calculating '1s * ops' for each number separately would mean we could optimise each number in isolation.

Comment: You say *"You are also not allowed to have numbers larger than 2^31-1 or smaller than -2^31+1 anywhere in the output"* yet have defined "/" to be floating-point. Surely that means you can generate "1/VERY_LARGE" as an intermediate result in the output which seems, to me, to go against the spirit of the challenge.

Comment: @SimonF How so?

Comment: Say I wanted to do (A*B)/(A+B), but (A*B) was too big. Then I could calculate 1 / (1/A + 1/B), which gives the same answer (modulo floating point rounding), but would give a different answer.

On that note, when you say 'floating point', what floating point? 32-bit? 64-bit? IEEE?

Comment: Well, that's extra operators in the output, then. It's fine by me.

Comment: Also, @ChrisJefferson, it's 32-bit rounding.

Comment: Too put some counterweight on what I perceive as negative comments, I love this challenge. Gives folks knowing only classic languages a shot and it does feel like puzzling.

Comment: Oh, I do like this challenge :) I personally have no interest in golfing, and that seems to be 99% of the site.

Comment: First thing I thought when reading the title: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0p_1QSUsbsM ; second thing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_J3VeogFUOs
— Freddy Mercury is alive!

Comment: For float there shouldn't be `[1-2^31,2^31-1]` or?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## C++11

Further small update: Do much less adding, and try all numbers of form A*B+C. I believe that, within the time limit, this is fairly close to optimal, assuming you only use `+`, `*` and `!`. I leave other operators to people with more time than me!

Small update: Try harder to make use of factorials and numbers like 11....111. Also fixed bug that I wasn't counting `!` in my costing

New result:

Primary Score = 3,810,660

Secondary Score = 12/09/2016 20:00

2532 `1`s, 1505 operators.

Various tricks put together. My program starts by setting the shortest program for all factorials and numbers of the form 111..111 (I don't think this falls foul of the hard-wiring rule, as these are the shortest ways to make these numbers. I could rearrange my code so I check these patterns in my dynamic programming if you want). Then do a partial dynamic programming approach, trying various forms:

- A + B
- A*B + C
- A! + B
- 11....11 + B

Unfortunately I can't try all the ways of decomposing a number, so I choose for factorial and 11...11 to only try the nearest number, for A+B to try things near A/2, and for A*B+C to try only quite small As.

It would be easy to extend this to try some '-'s, by trying to overshoot slightly sometimes (particular in A*B - C), but I quite like only trying to grow.

Also, it is very hard to optimise the optimisation condition (I don't like it!) because in principle you can't come up with a 'best' value for each number in isolation, you have to consider your set of answers globally (which I don't intend to do).

Warning: This program needs a 64-bit machine, and around 10GB of memory (as I inefficiently make a giant array for all partially-computed results).

Program:

```c++
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

std::vector<int> numints;
std::vector<int> numops;
std::vector<std::string> strings;


void fill_all_ones(long maxval)
{
    int val = 1;
    int len = 1;
    std::string name = "1";
    while(val < maxval) {
        val = val * 10 + 1;
        len++;
        name = name + "1";
        numints[val] = len;
        strings[val] = name;
    }
}


void get_best_for_next_full(long i);
// let's just assume this is the best way to make factorials
void fill_all_factorials(long maxval)
{
    // skip 1 and 2
    long result = 6;
    long val = 3;
    while(result < maxval) {
        get_best_for_next_full(val);
        strings[result] = "(" + strings[val] + ")!";
        numints[result] = numints[val];
        numops[result] = numops[val] + 1;
        val++;
        result = result * val;
    }
}

long get_nearest_all_ones(long i)
{
    int val = 11;
    int prevval = 1;
    while(val < i) {
        prevval = val;
        val = val * 10 + 1;
    }
    return prevval;
}

long get_nearest_factorial(long i)
{
    int val = 6;
    int prevval = 2;
    int step = 3;
    while(val < i) {
        prevval = val;
        step++;
        val = val * step;
    }
    return prevval;
}

int getlen(long i);

void get_best_for_next_full(long i)
{
    if(numints[i] > 0)
        return;

    int best = INT_MAX; // we'll do better than this
    std::string beststring = "invalid2";
    int ones = -1;
    int ops = -1;
    for(long loop = 1; loop <= i/2; loop++)
    {
        int new_val = getlen(loop) + getlen(i - loop);
        if(new_val < best) {
            best = new_val;
            ones = numints[loop] + numints[i - loop];
            beststring = "(" + strings[loop] + "+" + strings[i - loop] + ")";
            ops = numops[loop] + numops[i - loop] + 1;
        }
    }

    for(long loop = 2; loop * loop <= i; loop++)
    {
        long divisor = i / loop;
        long rem = i - loop*divisor;
        assert(rem >= 0);
        int new_val;
        if(rem == 0)
        {
            new_val = getlen(divisor) + getlen(loop);
        }
        else
        {
            new_val = getlen(divisor) + getlen(rem) + getlen(loop);
        }

        if(new_val < best) {
            best = new_val;
            if(rem == 0) {
                ones = numints[divisor] + numints[loop];
                beststring = "(" + strings[divisor] + "*" + strings[loop] + ")";
                ops = numops[divisor] + numops[loop] + 1;
            } else {
                ones = numints[divisor] + numints[loop] + numints[rem];
                beststring = "(" + strings[divisor] + "*" + strings[loop] + "+" + strings[rem] + ")";
                ops = numops[divisor] + numops[loop] + numops[rem] + 2;
            }
        }
    }

    numints[i] = ones;
    strings[i] = beststring;
    numops[i] = ops;
}


void check_divising(const long i, const long loop, long& best, long& ones, std::string& beststring, long& ops);
void check_adding(const long i, const long loop, long& best, long& ones, std::string& beststring, long& ops);

void get_best_for_next_partial(long i)
{
    if(numints[i] > 0)
        return;

    long best = INT_MAX; // we'll do better than this
    long ones = 1;
    std::string beststring = "invalid";
    long ops = 1;

    // Special: Try a nearby all ones
    {
        long loop = get_nearest_all_ones(i);
        check_adding(i, loop, best, ones, beststring, ops);
    }

    // Special: Try nearest factorial
    {
        long loop = get_nearest_factorial(i);
        check_adding(i, loop, best, ones, beststring, ops);
    }

    for(long loop = 2; loop * loop <= i; loop++)
    {
       check_divising(i, loop, best, ones, beststring, ops);
    }


    numints[i] = ones;
    strings[i] = beststring;
    numops[i] = ops;
}

void check_adding(const long i, const long loop, long& best, long& ones, std::string& beststring, long& ops)
{
    int new_val = getlen(loop) + getlen(i - loop);
    if(new_val < best) {
        best = new_val;
        ones = numints[loop] + numints[i - loop];
        beststring = "(" + strings[loop] + "+" + strings[i - loop] + ")";
            ops = numops[loop] + numops[i - loop] + 1;
    }
}

void check_divising(const long i, const long loop, long& best, long& ones, std::string& beststring, long& ops)
{ 
    long divisor = i / loop;
    long rem = i - loop*divisor;
    assert(rem >= 0);
    int new_val;
    if(rem == 0)
    {
        new_val = getlen(divisor) + getlen(loop);
    }
    else
    {
        new_val = getlen(divisor) + getlen(rem) + getlen(loop);
    }

    if(new_val < best) {
        best = new_val;
        if(rem == 0) {
            ones = numints[divisor] + numints[loop];
            beststring = "(" + strings[divisor] + "*" + strings[loop] + ")";
            ops = numops[divisor] + numops[loop] + 1;
        }
        else {
            ones = numints[divisor] + numints[loop] + numints[rem];
            beststring = "(" + strings[divisor] + "*" + strings[loop] + "+" + strings[rem] + ")";
            ops = numops[divisor] + numops[loop] + numops[rem] + 2;
        }
    }
}

long count = 0;
long countops = 0;

const int little_cutoff = 200000;

int getlen(long i)
{
    if(numints[i] == 0) {
        if(i < little_cutoff)
            get_best_for_next_full(i);
        else
            get_best_for_next_partial(i);
    }
    if(numints[i] == 0) {
        std::cout << i << " failure!" << numops[i] << ":" << strings[i] << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return numints[i] + numops[i];
}

const std::vector<long> vals = {945536, 16878234, 32608778, 42017515, 48950830, 51483452, 52970263, 54278649, 63636656, 78817406, 89918907, 90757642, 95364861, 102706605, 113965374, 122448605, 126594161, 148064959, 150735075, 154382918, 172057472, 192280850, 194713795, 207721209, 220946392, 225230299, 227043979, 241011012, 248906099, 249796314, 250546528, 258452706, 276862988, 277140688, 280158490, 286074562, 308946627, 310972897, 322612091, 324445400, 336060042, 346729632, 349428326, 352769482, 363039453, 363851029, 392168304, 401975104, 407890409, 407971913, 425780757, 459441559, 465592122, 475898732, 482826596, 484263150, 506235403, 548951531, 554295842, 580536366, 587051904, 588265985, 588298051, 590968352, 601194306, 607771869, 618578932, 626776380, 667919873, 681786366, 689854904, 692055400, 697665495, 711608194, 734027104, 750869335, 757710567, 759967747, 777616154, 830071127, 833809927, 835873060, 836438554, 836945593, 863728236, 864158514, 871273503, 881615667, 891619600, 897181691, 918159061, 920521050, 924502226, 929983535, 943162304, 950210939, 950214176, 962610357, 974842859, 988572832};

const long biggest = 988572832;



int main(void)
{
    numints.push_back(2);
    strings.push_back("(1-1)");
    numops.push_back(1);

    numints.push_back(1);
    strings.push_back("1");
    numops.push_back(0);

    numints.push_back(2);
    strings.push_back("(1+1)");
    numops.push_back(1);

    numints.resize(biggest + 1);
    strings.resize(biggest + 1);
    numops.resize(biggest + 1);

    fill_all_ones(biggest);
    fill_all_factorials(biggest);

    for(long i = 0; i < little_cutoff; ++i)
        get_best_for_next_full(i);




    for(long v : vals) {
        get_best_for_next_partial(v);
        std::cout << v << ":" << strings[v] << "\n";
        count += numints[v];
        countops += numops[v];

    }

    std::cout << count << ":" << countops << ":" << count * countops << "\n";

}
```

Results:

```
945536:((1111*(1+(11+11))+(1+1))*((1+11)*(1+(1+1))+1)+1)
16878234:(((1+(1+1111))*(1+(1+(1+111)))+(11+11))*((1+11)*11+1)+(1+1))
32608778:((((((1+(1+1)))!+(111+11111))*(11*11)+111)*(1+11)+1)*(1+1))
42017515:((11)!+((((1+111)*11)*11+1)*((1+11)*(1+11)+11)))
48950830:((((11+11)*(1+11))+(11111*(1+(1+1))))*((1+111)*(1+(1+11))+1)+1)
51483452:(((1+(1+1111))*(1+111)+1)*(11+(((1+11)*11+(1+1))*(1+(1+1))))+111)
52970263:((11+((1111*11+(1+(1+1)))*(1+(1+1))))*(111*(1+(1+11))+1)+11)
54278649:((11)!+(((1+(11+(11+(11+1111))))*111+1)*(1+(1+111))+1))
63636656:((((11+111)*(1+(1+1)))*(1+111)+11)*(1+(111+((((1+(1+1)))!)!*(1+1)))))
78817406:(((((111*(11+11)+1)*(1+1))*(1+111)+111)*(1+11)+1)*(1+11)+(1+1))
89918907:(((111+((1+(1+((1+(1+1)))!)))!)*(1+1))*(1+1111)+((11*11)*(1+(1+1))))
90757642:((1111+((11+11111)*(1+1)))*(111*(11+((1+(1+(1+1))))!)+1)+(1+111))
95364861:((11)!+(((((((11+11)*11)+11111)*111)*11+(1+1))*(1+1))*(1+1)+1))
102706605:(((11)!+(((111+((11*11)*11))*(1+(((1+(1+1)))!)!))*11))*(1+1)+1)
113965374:((((111*(1+(1+(1+11))))*1111+((1+(11+11))*11+1))*11+1)*((1+(1+1)))!)
122448605:(((((1+(1+1)))!)!+((111*11)*11))*((1+(((1+(1+1)))!)!)*(1+11)+1)+(1+1))
126594161:(((((11*11)+(((1+(1+1)))!)!)*(1+111))*(1+11)+1)*(1+111)+1)
148064959:((11)!+(((111*111+(1+11))*111+1)*((1+(1+11))*((1+(1+1)))!+1)+(1+(1+1))))
150735075:(((111*111+(1+1))*(1+1111)+(1+11))*11+(1+((1+(1+1)))!))
154382918:((1111*(1+11)+1)*(((1+(11+(111+111)))*(1+1))+11111)+111)
172057472:((((((1+11)*11)*11+1)*(1+(1+1)))+11111)*(11+11111)+((1+11)*11))
192280850:(((11111*(1+11)+11)*(1+(((1+(1+1)))!)!)+(11+111))*(1+1))
194713795:((11)!+((((111+11111)*(1+(1+(1+111)))+((1+(1+1)))!)*11)*11+1))
207721209:(((111*111)*(1+(11+11))+(1+1))*(1+(1+(11+(((1+(1+1)))!)!)))+(1+(1+(1+1))))
220946392:((11)!+((((1+(1+(1+1111)))*(11+111))*111+11)*(1+11)+(1+(1+(1+1)))))
225230299:((111111111+((111*111+(1+((1+(1+1)))!))*(11+111)+(11+11)))*(1+1)+1)
227043979:((((((11+11)*11)+11111)*(1+(1+1))+1)*1111+(1+(1+1)))*((1+(1+1)))!+1)
241011012:(((11)!+((11)!+((11)!+((11+1111)*((1+111)*((1+(1+1)))!+1)))))*(1+1))
248906099:(((11111+(((((1+(1+1)))!)!*111)*(1+1)))*(1+111)+111)*(1+(1+11)))
249796314:(((11)!+(((((1+(1+1)))!)!+((1+1111)*(1+11)))*(11+111)+111))*((1+(1+1)))!)
250546528:((11)!+(((111*111)*(1+(1+(1+11)))+11)*(111*11)+(1+(11+1111))))
258452706:(((11)!+(((((1+(1+1)))!)!*((1+(1+1)))!+1)*(11+(((1+(1+1)))!)!)))*((1+(1+1)))!)
276862988:(((11+(1111*(1+1)))*(((1+(1+1)))!+1111))*111+(((1+(1+1)))!+11))
277140688:(((111*111+(1+(1+(1+(1+11)))))*(1+1))*(11+(111+11111))+(1+111))
280158490:((11)!+(((1+(111+111111))*(((1+(1+1)))!)!+(1+(1+1)))*(1+(1+1))+1))
286074562:(((11)!+((((11+1111)*(11+11))*(1+1)+1)*(1+(11+1111))))*(1+(1+1))+1)
308946627:((11)!+((((1+1111)*(((1+(1+1)))!)!+((11+11)*(1+1)))*(1+111)+1)*(1+(1+1))))
310972897:((11111*(1+(1+1))+1)*(((1111+(111*11))*(1+1))*(1+1)+1)+11)
322612091:((((((1+11)*(1+11))*(1+11)+(1+1))*111+1)*(1+111))*(1+(1+(1+(1+11))))+11)
324445400:(((1111111+(1+(1+1)))*(1+1))*((1+11)*(1+11)+(1+1))+(1+111))
336060042:(((1+1111)*(1+(11+111))+(1+111))*(11+((111*11+1)*(1+1)))+(1+1))
346729632:(((1+(1+(11111+(111*111))))*((1+111)*11+1)+(1+(1+(1+11))))*(1+11))
349428326:(((((11+11)*11)*11+1)*(1+1111)+1)*(1+(((1+(1+1)))!+111)))
352769482:(((1+11111)*(111*(11+11))+((11+111)*((1+1)*(1+1)+1)))*(1+(1+11)))
363039453:(((((1+111)*(1+111)+1)*(1+1))*(1+(1+11))+11)*(1+(1+1111)))
363851029:((((111*11+1)*1111+11)*((1+11)*11+(1+1))+(1+11))*(1+1)+1)
392168304:(((((1+(1+1111))*(1+111))*11+1)*(1+(1+11))+11)*(11+11))
401975104:(((((1+11)*(1+11)+1)*111)*111+11)*((1+111)*(1+1)+1)+(1+(1+(1+1))))
407890409:(((1+11111)*11)*((1+1111)*(1+(1+1))+1)+((1+1111)*(1+1)+1))
407971913:((11)!+((11)!+(((1+(1+11111))*(1+1)+1)*(((11+111)*11)*11+1)+(1+1111))))
425780757:(((1111+((((1+11)*11)+11111)*(1+(1+1))))*11+1)*1111+((1+(1+1)))!)
459441559:(((11111+(((1+(1+111))*(1+1)+1)*111))*111+1)*(1+(1+(1+111)))+(1+(1+11)))
465592122:(((11)!+((((1111*(11*(1+(1+1))+1)+1)*(1+(11+11)))*(1+1)+1)*111))*(1+1))
475898732:(((11)!+(((((1+111)*11+(1+1))*(1+11))*(1+1)+1)*(1+(1+111))))*11+1)
482826596:(((1+(((111*11)*11)+(11111*(1+1))))*111+1)*(11+111)+((1+(1+1)))!)
484263150:(((111*111+(1+(1+1)))*111+11)*(1+(111+((11+11)*11))))
506235403:(((1+11))!+((((1+(1+1111))*(1+1111)+((11+111)*(1+1)))*11+1)*(1+1)+1))
548951531:((((111+111)*(1+1)+1)*111+11)*11111+((11+111)*(1+11)+1))
554295842:(((1+11))!+((((1+1111)*111+1)*((1+1)*(1+1)+1))*(11+111)+(1+111)))
580536366:(((1+(111+((111*111+11)*(1+11))))*(1+111)+1)*(11+((1+(1+(1+1))))!)+11)
587051904:(((((1+1111)*(1+11))*(1+(1+1))+1)*(111*11+1)+(111*((1+(1+1)))!))*(1+11))
588265985:(((1+11))!+((1+(111+(1111*(1+(1+11)))))*((1+111)*(11*((1+(1+1)))!+1)+(1+(1+1)))))
588298051:((((((11+111)*11)*11)+(11111*(1+(1+1))))*(1+1111)+1)*11)
590968352:(((((((1+(1+1)))!)!+11111)*111+(11+11))*((1+111)*(1+1)+1)+1)*(1+1))
601194306:((((1111*(1+(1+(1+(11+111))))+1)*111+(1+1))*(1+(1+1))+1)*(1+(1+11))+11)
607771869:(((1+11))!+(((11)!+(((1111*11+1)*(1+1))*(1+(11+111))+11))*(1+(1+1))))
618578932:(((((1111*111)*11+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1))*(1+(1+(1+111)))+(1+111))
626776380:((((1+(1+(1+1))))!+((((1+(1+1)))!)!+(1111*111)))*(1+(11+((1+((1+(1+1)))!))!)))
667919873:((((((1+(11+111))*11+1)*111+(1+(1+1)))*1111+1)*(1+1))*(1+1)+1)
681786366:(((1+11))!+((11)!+(((11)!+((11)!+((1+(1+11111))*((1+11)*(1+11))+111)))*(1+1))))
689854904:(((11+((11111+((1+1111)*11))*(1+1)))*((11+111)*11+1)+11)*11+(1+1))
692055400:(((1+11))!+(((((1+(1+111))*(1+(1+(1+11))))*11)*11+1)*(1+(1+1111))+1))
697665495:(((1+11))!+(((((((1+(1+1)))!)!*(1+(1+(1+111)))+1)*(1+11))*(1+1)+1)*111))
711608194:(((11)!+(((1+(1+(1+(1+1111))))*(11+((11+111)*(1+1)))+(1+1))*1111))*(1+1))
734027104:(((111*(11+((1+(1+(1+1))))!)+1)*(((1+(1+1)))!+11)+1)*11111+1111)
750869335:((11111111+((1+(((1+(1+1)))!)!)*((1+11)*11+1)+1))*(11*((1+(1+1)))!+1))
757710567:((((((11+111)*11)+111111)*(1+(1+1))+1)*(1+(11+1111))+(1+(1+1)))*(1+1)+1)
759967747:(((11)!+(((1+(1+(111+11111)))*(1+(1+111)))*(1+(11+11))+1))*11)
777616154:((11111*(111+(((111*11+1)*(1+1))*(1+1)))+(11+111))*(1+(1+(1+11))))
830071127:((((1+111)*111)*((1+(1+1)))!+1)*(((1+(1+1)))!+(11+11111))+(111*(1+1)+1))
833809927:((((11+1111)*(1+1)+1)*111+1)*(1+(1+(11+(1111*(1+(1+1))))))+111)
835873060:(((((11+(111+111))*111+1)*(1+(1+111))+1)*(1+(1+11))+1)*(11+11))
836438554:(((1+11))!+(((11111*(1+1)+1)*((11+(((1+(1+1)))!)!)*11+1)+1111)*(1+1)))
836945593:(((1111*1111+(1+111))*(1+(1+111))+(1+(1+1)))*((1+(1+1)))!+1)
863728236:(((1+(1111+((11+11111)*(1+1))))*(111*111+((1+(1+1)))!))*(1+(1+1)))
864158514:(((1+11))!+(((1111*(1+(1+(1+11)))+((1+(1+1)))!)*111+1)*(111*(1+1)+1)+11))
871273503:((((1+11111)*(11+11)+1)*((1+(1+11))*(1+1)+1)+1)*((1+11)*11)+111)
881615667:((11111+((111*111+11)*(1+1)))*((111*111)*(1+1)+1)+((11+1111)*11))
891619600:(((11)!+((11)!+((((1+(11+11))*(1+1))+111111)*11)))*11+(1+(1+1)))
897181691:((11+(11+(11+((1+(1+((1+(1+1)))!)))!)))*(11+(11111*(1+1)))+((111*11+1)*11))
918159061:(((11)!+(((11+11)*11+1)*(1+(1+11))))*(1+(11+11))+(1+(1+(1+1))))
920521050:(((11)!+((((1+(11+1111))*(1+(1+(1+1111))))*(1+111)+111)*(1+(1+1))))*(1+1))
924502226:((((1111*(1+11))*(1+1)+1)*((111*(1+11)+1)*(1+1)+1))*(1+(1+11))+11)
929983535:(((11)!+((((11+111)*111+1)*111)*((1+11)*(1+1)+1)+(1+1)))*(1+11)+11)
943162304:(((11)!+((((((1+((1+(1+1)))!))!+(111*111))*111+(1+1))*(1+111))*(1+1)))*(1+1))
950210939:(((11+(111+11111))*(1+(1+(1+(((1+(1+1)))!)!)))+(1+1))*(((1+(1+1)))!+111)+(1+1))
950214176:(((11)!+((((111*111)*(1+(1+11)))*11+1)*((1+(11+111))*(1+1)+1)))*(1+1))
962610357:((((1+11))!+((1+((((1+(1+1)))!)!+(111*(1+11))))*(11+1111)+(1+111)))*(1+1)+1)
974842859:((((((11*(1+((1+(1+1)))!))+1111)*11+1)*(1+111))*((1+(1+1)))!)*111+11)
988572832:(((111111111+((11111*(1+(1+1111))+11)*11+(1+(1+1))))*(1+1))*(1+1))
```

Comment: Seems like you didn't count the 225 `!`. I think that's 1632 operators, not 1407. (Which still leads to a great score, though.)

Comment: Woops, indeed, I missed a '1' in the costing of factorial functions.

Suprisingly (to me) fixing that makes almost no difference to the expressions I generate, I suppose because factorials are generally so great, that if they cost one more they are still the best choice.

Comment: `long maxval` *grumble grumble*

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell

**Primary score: 27242281**

**Secondary score: 12/09/2016 09:01**

**11891 `1`'s, 2291 operators**

```
import Data.List


nums = iterate (\x -> x*10+1) 1

g n | n > a = show a ++ "+(" ++ g (n-a) ++ ")"
    | n < a = show a ++ "-(" ++ g (a-n) ++ ")"
    | otherwise = show a
 where a = minimumBy (\x y -> compare (abs$x-n) (abs$y-n))
         . take 2 . reverse
         $ takeWhile (<=n*10) nums
```

It basically finds the shortest way to make it using only + and -

Output:

```
945536: 1111111-(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111-(11+(11-(1+(1)))))))))))
16878234: 11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111-(11111-(111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(1+(1)))))))))))))))
32608778: 11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(111-(1)))))))))))))))
42017515: 11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))
48950830: 11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))
51483452: 11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(11-(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))
52970263: 11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))
54278649: 11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111-(111+(111+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))
63636656: 111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111-(11)))))))))))))))))
78817406: 111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111-(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))
89918907: 111111111-(11111111+(11111111-(1111111-(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111-(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))
90757642: 111111111-(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111-(111+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))
95364861: 111111111-(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))
102706605: 111111111-(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))
113965374: 111111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))
122448605: 111111111+(11111111+(111111+(111111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))
126594161: 111111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))
148064959: 111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))
150735075: 111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
154382918: 111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))
172057472: 111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
192280850: 111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))
194713795: 111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))
207721209: 111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111-(111-(11+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))
220946392: 111111111+(111111111-(1111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))
225230299: 111111111+(111111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(1))))))))))))))))))
227043979: 111111111+(111111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11-(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))
241011012: 111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111-(11111-(111-(11+(1)))))))))))
248906099: 111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(111-(11-(1))))))))))))))))))))
249796314: 111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))
250546528: 111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111-(1111+(1111-(111+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))
258452706: 111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))
276862988: 111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111-(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(1)))))))))))))))))))
277140688: 111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(11)))))))))))))))))))))))
280158490: 111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))
286074562: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))
308946627: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111-(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))
310972897: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111-(11-(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))
322612091: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111-(111+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))
324445400: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111-(111+(11+(11+(11+(11)))))))))))
336060042: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(11+(11+(11+(11)))))))))))))))))))))
346729632: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))
349428326: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))
352769482: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))
363039453: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(111-(11-(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
363851029: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111-(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
392168304: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
401975104: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(11-(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))
407890409: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))
407971913: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))
425780757: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111+(11+(11-(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))
459441559: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111+(111+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))
465592122: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111-(11+(1)))))))))))))))
475898732: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111-(1111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11+(1)))))))))))))))))))
482826596: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111-(11+(11+(11+(11-(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
484263150: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
506235403: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(1111+(1111-(111+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))
548951531: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))
554295842: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(1111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))
580536366: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))
587051904: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
588265985: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111-(111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))
588298051: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
590968352: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11-(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))
601194306: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))
607771869: 111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11-(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))
618578932: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(1111+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))
626776380: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111-(1111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))
667919873: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(1111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(111+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))
681786366: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111-(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11-(1)))))))))))))))))))))))
689854904: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(1111111-(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111-(111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))
692055400: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11+(1)))))))))))))))))))))
697665495: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(1111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))
711608194: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
734027104: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111-(11-(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))
750869335: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(1))))))))))))))))))))
757710567: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111-(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(111+(111+(111+(111+(111-(11))))))))))))))))))
759967747: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111-(11+(11+(11-(1+(1))))))))))))))))))
777616154: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(111111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))
830071127: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))
833809927: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))
835873060: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))
836438554: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))
836945593: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))
863728236: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))
864158514: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))
871273503: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(11+(11+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
881615667: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))
891619600: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111-(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(11)))))))))))))))))))))))
897181691: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111-(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))
918159061: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
920521050: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))
924502226: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))
929983535: 1111111111-(111111111+(111111111-(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111-(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111-(11+(11-(1))))))))))))))))))))
943162304: 1111111111-(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111-(111-(11+(11+(11-(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))
950210939: 1111111111-(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111-(11111+(111+(111-(11+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))
950214176: 1111111111-(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111-(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111-(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))))
962610357: 1111111111-(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111-(1111-(111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))
974842859: 1111111111-(111111111+(11111111+(11111111+(1111111+(1111111+(1111111-(111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111+(11111+(11111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(11-(1+(1))))))))))))))))))))))))
988572832: 1111111111-(111111111+(11111111+(111111+(111111+(111111-(11111+(11111-(1111+(1111+(1111+(1111+(111+(111+(111+(111+(11+(11+(11+(11+(11+(1+(1+(1)))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python, score 17136288

secondary score: 12/09/2016 08:53
(4784 ones and 3582 operations)

Work in progress but OP asked for my current code...

```python
# get number in factorial base, ignoring the place of 0! (always 0) 
r=lambda n,q=[],i=2:n and r(n//i,q+[n%i],i+1)or q

# rewrite a number in a form using only 1s by converting its factorial base, the range only requires using up to 12 places, again ignoring the 0! place so we only hard code 1 and [5-12] (9 numbers)
def g(n):
    k=['','1']+['1'+'+1'*i for i in range(1,4)]+['(11-1)/(1+1)','t(1+1+1)','1+t(1+1+1)','11-1-1-1','11-1-1','11-1','11','1+11']
    q=r(n)
    return n<13and k[n]or(q[0]and'1+'or'')+'+'.join((v>1and'('+k[v]+')*'or'')+(i>2and't'or'')+'('+k[i]+')'for i,v in enumerate(q[1:],2)if v)

#get g(n) representations after differencing from 0, 11, 111, 1111, ... then return the one with the minimal stand-alone score
def h(n):
    o=[g(n)]+[str(v)+(v<n and'+('or'-(')+g(abs(v-n))+')'for v in[int('1'*l)for l in range(2,11)]]
    s=[sum(map(v.count,'+-*/t'))*v.count('1')for v in o]
    return o[s.index(min(s))]

# A Factorial function for analysis with eval
def t(n):
    r = 1
    while n:
        r *= n
        n -= 1
    return r
```

Output - note that `t` is the factorial function, so as not to be confused with `f` for `floor` if it gets used - I evaluated each using the function `t` (above) to double check that they are all correct:

```
945536 11111111-(1+(1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1))
16878234 11111111+(1+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(t(1+1+1))+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1-1)+t(11-1))
32608778 111111111-(1+(1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(11-1)*t(11-1)+t(11))
42017515 111+((1+1)*(1+1)+(1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1-1)+t(11))
48950830 111+(1+t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1)+t(11))
51483452 11111111+(1+(1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+t(11-1-1)+t(11))
52970263 111111111-((1+1)+t(1+1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1)+t(11))
54278649 1+(1+1)+t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+t(1+t(1+1+1))+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11-1)+t(11)
63636656 1111111+(1+t(1+1+1+1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1)+t(11))
78817406 1111+(1+t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(11-1)*t(11-1)+t(11))
89918907 1+(1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1)+(1+1)*t(11)
90757642 1111111+(1+(1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1)+(1+1)*t(11))
95364861 11111111+((1+1)*(1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+t(11-1)+(1+1)*t(11))
102706605 1111+((1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1)+(1+1)*t(11))
113965374 t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11-1)+(1+1)*t(11)
122448605 111111+((1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11))
126594161 111111111+((1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1))
148064959 1111111111-((1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+t(11-1)+(1+1)*t(1+11))
150735075 11111111+((1+1)*(1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11))
154382918 1111111+(1+t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11))
172057472 1111+(1+t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11))
192280850 1111111111-(1+(1+1)*(1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(11)*t(11)+t(1+11))
194713795 111111111+((1+1)*(1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t((11-1)/(1+1))+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+t(11-1)+(1+1)*t(11))
207721209 111111+((1+1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11))
220946392 111111111+(1+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1)+(1+1)*t(11))
225230299 1111111111-((1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+t(11-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1)+(11-1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
227043979 1111111111-((1+1)*t(1+1+1)+t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+t(11-1)+(11-1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
241011012 11+(1+(1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11))
248906099 11+((1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11))
249796314 111111+(1+(1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11))
250546528 111+(1+(1+1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11))
258452706 11+(1+t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11))
276862988 111+(1+(1+1)*(1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1)*t(11-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11))
277140688 1111+(1+(1+1)+t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1)*t(11-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11))
280158490 (1+1)*(1+1)+t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11)
286074562 1111+(1+(1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1-1)+t(11-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11))
308946627 11111+((1+1)*(1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11))
310972897 111111111+((1+1)*(1+1)+t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11))
322612091 11+((1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(11-1-1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11))
324445400 1111+(1+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+t(11-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11))
336060042 11+(1+t(1+1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11))
346729632 11111+(1+(1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11))
349428326 11+(1+(1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11))
352769482 1111+(1+(1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11))
363039453 111111+(t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+t(11-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11))
363851029 1111+(t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+t(11-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11))
392168304 11111111+(1+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11))
401975104 1111111+(1+(1+1)+t(1+1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1)*t(11))
407890409 11111+((1+1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1)+(11-1)*t(11))
407971913 11111+((1+1+1)*t(1+1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1)+(11-1)*t(11))
425780757 111+(t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1)+(11-1)*t(11))
459441559 1111111+((1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1)+(11)*t(11))
465592122 1111+(1+(1+1)*(1+1)+t(1+1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1)+(11)*t(11))
475898732 11111+(1+(1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1)+t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+t(11-1-1)+(11-1)*t(11-1)+(11)*t(11))
482826596 111111+(1+(1+1)*(1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+t(11-1)+t(1+11))
484263150 t(1+1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+t(11-1)+t(1+11)
506235403 1111+((1+1)*t(1+1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1)+t(1+11))
548951531 11+((1+1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1)+t(11)+t(1+11))
554295842 (1+1)+(1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11-1)+t(11)+t(1+11)
580536366 1111111111-(1+t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11-1)+t(11)+t(1+11))
587051904 1111111111-(1+t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+t(11-1)+t(11)+t(1+11))
588265985 11+(t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1)+(1+1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
588298051 11111111+((1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(t(1+1+1))+t(1+t(1+1+1))+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1)+(1+1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
590968352 1111111+(1+t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1)+(1+1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
601194306 1111111+(1+(1+1)*(1+1)+t(1+1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
607771869 1111111+((1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(t(1+1+1))+t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+t(11-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
618578932 111111111+(1+(1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1)+t(1+11))
626776380 1111+(1+(1+1)*(1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
667919873 111111+((1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
681786366 t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11)+t(1+11)
689854904 1111+(1+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11)+t(1+11))
692055400 11+(1+(1+1)*(1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11)+t(1+11))
697665495 1111111111-((1+1)*(1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11-1)+(11-1)*t(11))
711608194 (1+1)*(1+1)+t(1+1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11)+t(1+11)
734027104 11+(1+(1+1)*(1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11)+t(1+11))
750869335 111111111+((1+1)*(1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
757710567 11111+((1+1)*(1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(t(1+1+1))+t(1+t(1+1+1))+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1)*t(11-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11)+t(1+11))
759967747 1111+((1+1)*t(1+1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11)+t(1+11))
777616154 11111+(1+(1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11)+t(1+11))
830071127 1111+((1+1)*(1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
833809927 1111111111-(t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1)*t(11-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11))
835873060 1111111111-(1+(1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11))
836438554 111+(1+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(11-1)*t(11-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
836945593 11111111+((1+1)+(1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
863728236 1111+(1+(1+1)*(1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
864158514 111+(1+(1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+t(11-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
871273503 111111111+((1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11)+t(1+11))
881615667 111+((1+1)*t(1+1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
891619600 1111111+(1+(1+1)+t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11-1)+(11-1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
897181691 111111+((1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1)+(11-1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
918159061 1111+(t(1+1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(11)*t(11)+t(1+11))
920521050 11111+(1+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(11)*t(11)+t(1+11))
924502226 (1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+t(11-1)+(11)*t(11)+t(1+11)
929983535 1111111111-((1+1)+t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+t(11-1-1-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11))
943162304 1111+(1+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+t(t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(11-1-1)*t(11-1-1)+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1)+(11)*t(11)+t(1+11))
950210939 111111111+((1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1)*t(11)+t(1+11))
950214176 1111111+(1+t(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1-1-1)+((11-1)/(1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(11-1-1-1)*t(11-1)+(11)*t(11)+t(1+11))
962610357 111+(t(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)*t((11-1)/(1+1))+(1+1)*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+1)*t(11-1-1)+t(11-1)+(1+1)*t(1+11))
974842859 111111+((1+1)+(1+1+1)*t(1+1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1+1)+t(t(1+1+1))+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(1+t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1+1)*t(11-1)+(1+1)*t(1+11))
988572832 1111111111-(1+(1+1)+(1+1)*t(1+1+1)+t(1+1+1+1)+t(t(1+1+1))+t(1+t(1+1+1))+(t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1-1)+(1+t(1+1+1))*t(11-1-1)+(1+1+1)*t(11))
```

Comment: What are all these `t`s in the output?

Comment: @QBrute heh, was just writing in a note for that

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the time was 8:52, but eh.

Comment: It only makes sense to go by the timestamp provided by SE (hover over the approximate time in the revision history to see the exact time). The time of the score being achieved was 08:53:13

Comment: (Doesn't make a difference to who wins in this case - just seems like the best way to clear up any disagreements elsewhere...)

Answer (score 4):

## Python

**Primary Score = 2214138604871819402525**

**Secondary Score = 12/09/2016, 07:53**

Here is the code:

```python
def print_1s(n):
    return ("1+" * n)[:-1]
```

Just to get the ball rollin'.

Basically outputs `1+1+1...+1`, where the number of `1`'s in the outputted expression is equal to `n`.

In total, there are `47054634305` `1`'s for the set of numbers, and `47054634205` operators (which are all `+`'s).

Not going to post a pastebin here, because you get the idea.

Comment: Does this actually fulfill all the requirements? I'm getting an Overflow-error when calling it with `2**31-1`.

Comment: @Jakube Heh, heh, heh...

Comment: @trichoplax How does it sum to `n-1`? It works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 27212498, 2016-09-12 09:46:34Z

```js
f=(n,a='+',s='-',m=n*9+'',r=m.replace(/./g,1))=>r-n?m<'55'?--r/10+a+f(n-r/10,a,s):r+s+f(r-n,s,a):r;
s = '';
[945536, 16878234, 32608778, 42017515, 48950830, 51483452, 52970263, 54278649, 63636656, 78817406, 89918907, 90757642, 95364861, 102706605, 113965374, 122448605, 126594161, 148064959, 150735075, 154382918, 172057472, 192280850, 194713795, 207721209, 220946392, 225230299, 227043979, 241011012, 248906099, 249796314, 250546528, 258452706, 276862988, 277140688, 280158490, 286074562, 308946627, 310972897, 322612091, 324445400, 336060042, 346729632, 349428326, 352769482, 363039453, 363851029, 392168304, 401975104, 407890409, 407971913, 425780757, 459441559, 465592122, 475898732, 482826596, 484263150, 506235403, 548951531, 554295842, 580536366, 587051904, 588265985, 588298051, 590968352, 601194306, 607771869, 618578932, 626776380, 667919873, 681786366, 689854904, 692055400, 697665495, 711608194, 734027104, 750869335, 757710567, 759967747, 777616154, 830071127, 833809927, 835873060, 836438554, 836945593, 863728236, 864158514, 871273503, 881615667, 891619600, 897181691, 918159061, 920521050, 924502226, 929983535, 943162304, 950210939, 950214176, 962610357, 974842859, 988572832].forEach(n => { s += f(n); console.log(n, f(n)); });
l = s.match(/1/g).length;
console.log((s.length - l) * l);
```

Only uses + and -. Based on my answer to [Minimize Those Ones](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79207/minimize-those-ones/79226)

Comment: 2106? This is a really late answer :P

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3

**Primary Score: `69720516`**

**Secondary Score: `09:30 14/09/2016`**

```py
def genNum(num):
    dic = { 
        6: "(1+1+1)!",
        24: "(1+1+1+1)!",
        120: "((1+1+1)!-1)!",
        720: "((1+1+1)!)!",
        5040: "((1+1+1)!+1)!",
        40320: "((1+1+1)!+1+1)!",
        362880: "(11-1-1)!",
        39916800: "(11)!",
        479001600: "(11+1)!",
        6227020800: "(11+1+1)!"
    }

    lis = [6227020800,479001600,39916800,362880,40320,5040,720,120,24,6]
    out = ""

    for i in lis:
        if num/i >= 1:
            st = dic[i] + "*(" + genNum(num // i) + ")"
            out += st

            if num%i != 0:
               out += "+" + genNum(num%i)

          return out

    else:
        st = "1+"*num

    return st[:-1]
```

***Edit:*** Now uses multiplication to greatly reduce the score.

This makes great use of factorials and recursion. In total, the program uses:

- **`5958` ones**
- **`11702` operators**

[**Ideone it!**](https://ideone.com/mDspXr)

Answer (score 2):

## awk

**primary score 46933701**

**secondary score 12/09/2016 19:20**

**(6901 ones, 6801 ops)**

```
{
    for(b=""; $0; $0=int($0/2))
        b=and($0, 1) b
    for(chall=""; length(b=substr(b,2)); ) {
        if(chall!="")
            chall=chall"*"
        chall=chall"(1+1)"
        if(substr(b, 1, 1)=="1") {
            chall=chall"+1"
            if(length(b)>1)
                chall="("chall")"
        }
    }
    print chall
}
```

Simply prints the binary representation calculated from left to right.

For example 19 is 10011 which is (((((**1**)*2+**0**)*2+**0**)*2+**1**)*2+**1**).

I just leave out the `+0` and write the `2` as `(1+1)`.

I was just curious about how this method would be scoring.

Output:

```
945536: (((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
16878234: (((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
32608778: (((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
42017515: ((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
48950830: ((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
51483452: ((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
52970263: ((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
54278649: (((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
63636656: (((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
78817406: ((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
89918907: ((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
90757642: ((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
95364861: (((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
102706605: (((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
113965374: (((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
122448605: (((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
126594161: ((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
148064959: (((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
150735075: ((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
154382918: (((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
172057472: (((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
192280850: ((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
194713795: (((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
207721209: (((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
220946392: (((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
225230299: ((((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
227043979: ((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
241011012: (((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
248906099: (((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
249796314: (((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
250546528: ((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
258452706: (((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
276862988: (((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
277140688: ((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
280158490: ((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
286074562: (((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
308946627: ((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
310972897: ((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
322612091: (((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
324445400: ((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
336060042: ((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
346729632: ((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
349428326: ((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
352769482: ((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
363039453: (((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
363851029: (((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
392168304: (((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
401975104: ((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
407890409: ((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
407971913: (((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
425780757: ((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
459441559: ((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
465592122: ((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
475898732: ((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
482826596: (((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
484263150: (((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
506235403: ((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
548951531: ((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
554295842: ((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
580536366: ((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
587051904: (((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
588265985: ((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
588298051: ((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
590968352: (((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
601194306: (((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
607771869: ((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
618578932: (((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
626776380: (((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
667919873: ((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
681786366: ((((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
689854904: (((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
692055400: ((((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
697665495: ((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
711608194: (((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
734027104: (((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
750869335: (((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
757710567: ((((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
759967747: ((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
777616154: (((((((((((((((((1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
830071127: ((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
833809927: (((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
835873060: (((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
836438554: ((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
836945593: (((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
863728236: ((((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
864158514: (((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
871273503: (((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
881615667: (((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
891619600: ((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
897181691: (((((((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
918159061: ((((((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
920521050: ((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
924502226: (((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)
929983535: ((((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
943162304: (((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
950210939: ((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
950214176: ((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
962610357: ((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1
974842859: ((((((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1
988572832: (((((((((((((((1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Emacs Lisp

**Primary score: 81638725**
**Secondary score: 12/09/2016 09:35**

```
(defun 1s (n)
  (let((x 1)r)
    (while (> (/ n x) 11)
      (setq x (1+ (* x 10))))
    (while (> n 0)
      (while (>= n x)
        (push x r)
        (push '+ r)
        (setq n (- n x)))
      (setq x (/ x 10)))
    r))
```

Basically builds a sum over the domain (1, 11, 111, ...) which is equivalent to n.

Comment: From what I understand, in your program, when it gets an input like 124, it outputs `111+11+1+1`, right? (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: (Also, the time is in GMT.)

Comment: How can this have a score of < 1million? Have you added up all the `1`s across the whole 100 number output and multiplied that by the total number of `+` operations across the whole output?

Comment: This has a score of 81638725

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted. is there something wrong?

Comment: @tuskiomi the score is calculated incorrectly (see the challenge post for the scoring method).

Comment: I updated the score now to what Jonathan calculated. Also fixed the time (hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

## JAVA

**Primary Score** `1045978739`

**Secondary score**      `12/09/2016 16:05`

37193  `1s`

28123  `operators`

```
     void main() {

    int arr[]={945536, 16878234, 32608778, 42017515, 48950830, 51483452, 52970263, 54278649, 63636656, 78817406, 89918907, 90757642, 95364861, 102706605, 113965374, 122448605, 126594161, 148064959, 150735075, 154382918, 172057472, 192280850, 194713795, 207721209, 220946392, 225230299, 227043979, 241011012, 248906099, 249796314, 250546528, 258452706, 276862988, 277140688, 280158490, 286074562, 308946627, 310972897, 322612091, 324445400, 336060042, 346729632, 349428326, 352769482, 363039453, 363851029, 392168304, 401975104, 407890409, 407971913, 425780757, 459441559, 465592122, 475898732, 482826596, 484263150, 506235403, 548951531, 554295842, 580536366, 587051904, 588265985, 588298051, 590968352, 601194306, 607771869, 618578932, 626776380, 667919873, 681786366, 689854904, 692055400, 697665495, 711608194, 734027104, 750869335, 757710567, 759967747, 777616154, 830071127, 833809927, 835873060, 836438554, 836945593, 863728236, 864158514, 871273503, 881615667, 891619600, 897181691, 918159061, 920521050, 924502226, 929983535, 943162304, 950210939, 950214176, 962610357, 974842859, 988572832

};
    int sum=1;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    System.out.print(arr[i]+":");
        while(arr[i]>11){
            System.out.print("("+"1");
            sum=11;
            while(sum<=arr[i]){
            if(sum<=arr[i])
            System.out.print("*11");
            sum*=11;
        }
        arr[i]=arr[i]-sum/11;
        System.out.print(")");
        if(arr[i]!=0)
        System.out.print("+");

        }
        while(arr[i]--!=0){
        System.out.print(1);
        if(arr[i]!=0)
            System.out.print("+");
    }

        System.out.println();



    }
    }
```

```
945536:(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
16878234:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
32608778:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+1+1+1+1
42017515:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1
48950830:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1
51483452:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
52970263:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1
54278649:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
63636656:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1
78817406:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
89918907:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1
90757642:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
95364861:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
102706605:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1
113965374:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1
122448605:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1
126594161:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1
148064959:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
150735075:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
154382918:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
172057472:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1
192280850:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1
194713795:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1
207721209:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1
220946392:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
225230299:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
227043979:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
241011012:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1
248906099:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1
249796314:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
250546528:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1
258452706:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
276862988:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
277140688:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1
280158490:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
286074562:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1
308946627:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1
310972897:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1
322612091:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1
324445400:(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+(1*11)+1+1+1+1+1+1
```

Comment: I think you can get rid of the unnecessary `1`'s at the beginning of each `(1*11*11*...*11)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 15642720

Secondary Score=30/05/2017, 21:11

```
BEGIN{RS="[,\n]"}
func f2(x) {
  div=int(x/11)
  mod=x%11
}
func trans(z){
  r=""
  if (z > 6) {
    r="11"
    for (i=11;i>z;i--){
      r=r"-1"
    }
  } else if (z>0){
    r=r 1
    for (i=1;i<z;i++){
      r=r"+1"
    }
  }
}
{n=$1
 do {f2(n)
   trans(mod)
   if (r) s=s"(" r  ")"
   if(div){
     if (r)s=s"+"
     s=s"11*("
     count++
   }
   n=div
 } while(div >10)
 trans(div)
 s = s r
 for (i=0;i<count;i++)s = s")"
 print $1": " s
 slength+=length(s)
 ones+=gsub("1","",s);
 parens+=gsub("[()]","",s);
 ops+=length(s);
 s=""
 count=0;
}
END {
  print "Total string length: " slength
  print "Ones: " ones
  print "Ops: " ops
  print "Parens: " parens
  print "Primary Score="ones*ops
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#VVNNbxtHDL3rVwwWKSBFMkrOBzmsuz4UDYpc0qLpLc3BtWVHgLMyduU2teHf7j7Oyo0DSau3Mxy@R/LN009vfnn77uH39333YfPn8LF7XFzdDRfhKi6/rMLDIoTL3d/9bjgsv3zPvML75/1l/@U75sUx8jCeD9PyfuWxY991@NtdheV9OAsyZ2jrzF2DV/sxLHc98@nu7P50d3KymkM8aOxOjlGPeD6G7c20nZOd0eo50xj4m0Snux@RZ73@Js/6ZR4ofRj6Vzh2uQ8PqGzwOo7CUU57c5pxFaZ@6pZdGEPoVt28vkQHnpPPUR60ngnaAebXy@Prxf5uOKzXiyN3GHqcXqCWfz7tbraeKpwxgXFm99SLMIUev3HxXBOhppao1dV2m5rbEYMIr7j7IXRhwrmb7XB9@LTu5//lhFz7YTut@@vp7q9lx92m6zbT6hRHz8ft8P/Gh@Xq49e9/e30IgUWpjbGpgBa0L43735uk5wFdH/sD@c3YTrg7TrMB5uiGX6N@xVafMM1vVi9nRdvX6z91uT58iz0xc64@3w@/hveX@zHbd95qtd@9HHx9GS5lCSbwFK1xpQ3IUWhqlo3IUdiLVyAqhWqiTahcK4plwgUTSlKAspRq2TbBEn4SEE@rZU1E1A142qkm4BHUck4a@DMVRi8FJVECCTMyaQkhQaOMWO/rUYplrnF5kqgKSDiQprw84CSU43gANRIRbOCgS3GSrWQw6yc1BAbSTVyJGSIeGZJFh2WmChaW1XKydRhZmJ8PQD1k1ALyNiUxBAZC5UsJVaHFT1RLzeqVIlWfVWV0YIGKzFijBwKaS6CvIkqNEhEbxKTaazmMEZxjeww51wy4VhKAgnk3UtZNEJEg5ZjxcgAIUAsV1@VRAmTTQ3WgiZDOmrFlBNBeiY2THaGiuKytwTQlI2Tj75o9XEBov2Zi3cd1RYkiaDIWqpVdQ2grD4kcZjhCPauF5KYIL35A/bhklBQgVcMjXD/VCrNLg6VCpvLKbXlqmWGhiA/ZmSQ7rYTDMVy8lajj@hwFTceVwg2lyNRVFE1NIiosasEhB3rzCYQXnJjE4Nh5v6KKZyb3SXKjCsAFsCUYdDWKMUNEEvJAwp4qYg6NANfdgha@LQgFl0mZPHB1gQpZjNEoVBODgWuLXOs@CU0iIRAeCD6fcR9gmGK@6wqEsHsHlCdQJy4GqCJS4drGBtuGFwDRrP8tnhpESrJYS4Uo7vEYHPo8CrQRcaMvDbcboRasiPMrB6LVjIlN4Gpj7a6CWDtou65/wA)

Ones: 4590

Ops: 3408
Primary Score=15642720
Secondary Score=30/05/2017 21:11